# mongodb: array filtering by index or another field

Tags: mongodb

When filtering an array, is it possible:

1. filter by item index (e.g. get all array elements but the first)?
2. filter by value in another field within the same document that contains the array field?

Consider document:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   first_seen_on: 20160312,
   seen_on: [20160312, 20160313, 20160324]
}
```

I need the `seen_on` array to become [20160313, 20160324]

This doesn't seem to work (I think `$first_seen_on` is treated as literal value):

```
        'repeats': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$seen_on', 
                'as': 'date', 
                'cond': {'$ne': ['$date', '$first_seen_on']}
            }
```

Comment: when you say filtering, you refer to the filter stage in the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Filtering an array, like in the sample code I included, in the project stage of the aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** as follows

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "repeats": {
                "$setDifference": ["$seen_on", ["$first_seen_on"]]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "repeats" : [ 
        20160313, 
        20160324
    ]
}
```